# Can you use a @StateObject under SwiftUI App protocol?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, observableobject

I have created an `ObservableObject` like so:

```swift
class Status: ObservableObject {
  @Published var status: StatusType = .stopped
}
```

Which uses a custom enum `StatusType` that has 4 states.

I am using this `ObservableObject` in a `View` to get and set `StatusType`'s.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
  @StateObject private var myStatus = Status()
  
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      switch myStatus.status {
      case .stopped:
        start()
        myStatus.status = .started
      // more cases...

      }
   }){
      switch myStatus.status {
      case .stopped:
        Text("Stopped")
      // more cases...
   }
}
```

This works pretty well.

But when I try to use a `@StateObject` under the `App` protocol, it doesn't work. Xcode doesn't complain either.

I want to use the `@StateObject` to change my `menuIcon`.

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
  @StateObject private var myStatus = Status()

  private var menuIcon: String {
    return myStatus.status == .started ? "started" : "stopped"
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    MenuBarExtra {
    // views
    } label: {
      // use menuIcon here
      }
  }

}
```

What am I missing? Would appreciate some pointers!

Comment: `@Published` does not *trigger* a computed property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to observe the status object, You can make your Status a singleton. This ensures that there is only one instance of it throughout the app

```
class Status: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Status()

    @Published var status: StatusType = .stopped
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @ObservedObject private var myStatus = Status.shared
    
    //... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This makes no difference at all. The problem is the computed property.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @vadian what is your suggestion?

Comment: If you use `myStatus.status` directly in the `body` the view will be refreshed, but not in the computed variable `menuIcon`, regardless of using `@StateObject` or a singleton.

Comment: Actually using a computed variable `menuIcon` works after the singleton implementation. But I've switched to using `myStatus.status` directly in the `body` since it might be safer that way. Thanks for the suggestion.